# Delete files older than last 14 days in windows IIS server

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want to write a **recipe in Chef** to delete all files mentioned in **C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1** which are older than 14 days.

So at any given day I should not have files older than 2 weeks.

```
Dir['C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*.log'].each do |path|
  file path do
    action :delete
    backup false
    only_if { ###not sure how to include the timestamp### }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing that you can do something like this:

For getting the time in a file

```
[7] pry(main)> ::File.stat("/Users/toni/certs/openconnect_mac_scripts/openConnectMac.sh").ctime
=> 2020-11-22 07:13:57.367508716 +0100
```

Now time:

```
[8] pry(main)> Time.now
=> 2021-01-13 18:27:31.472653 +0100
```

calculating date (60 * 60 * 24 * 14) seconds, minutes, hours, days

```
[2] pry(main)> (Time.now - (60 * 60 * 24 * 14))
=> 2020-12-30 18:17:18.1294 +0100
```

Then in ruby you can compare times mith < and > so:

you will get:

```
Dir['C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*.log'].each do |path|
  file path do
    action :delete
    only_if { ::File.stat(path).ctime < (Time.now - (60 * 60 * 24 * 14) ) }
  end
end
```